# AJAX call not being called for successive pages for table spread over more than one page - javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination

I have an ajax call (for updating a table column dependent on another column's value) being made on windows.onload(). The table lists search results which span over multiple pages. The ajax function works well for the first page, but moving on to the next pages, the ajax function doesn't get called for updating the column in the table. Looking for some suggestions here.

Comment: Perhaps moving to second page doesn not entails a full page refresh, leading to ```onload()``` not being called

Comment: that is true. What do I do in this case?

Comment: Depends on whether datatable library you're using allows ```callbacks``` to be attached to pagination events.. if so, perhaps you can run the ```onload``` logic on pagination change